# JavaFX MediaPlayer just stops after 1 minute+

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm using the MediaPlayer class in JavaFX to run the media the whole time untill you close the application but the MediaPlayer just stops after 1 minute and the file is 11 minutes long. This is my code:

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
        File file = chooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
        Media media = null;
        if(file != null) {
            media = new Media(file.toURI().toString());
        }
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
        mediaPlayer.play();
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. Tried running it and it just stops the media fine. Can you please tell us which type of media are you playing. As an alternative, can you & try adding the following piece of code inside start() `primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(windowEvent -> {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        });`

Comment: It's a mp3 file and it runs fine if i don't use this application.

Comment: Weird after i added that it worked again

Comment: Well, I tested it with a `.mp3` file and it works fine. Can you drop in more details on the environment you are using?

Comment: I got it working by adding that setOnCloseRequest thanks for your help

Comment: Well, I still want to know the environment, just to know if it is a bug in javafx environment. If yes, I would file a JIRA to fix it with the developers.

Comment: I tried jdk 1.8.0_25 and 1.8.0_31 and the early version of 1.8.0_40 and it happend at all of them but now it works again and i have no idea why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70964/discussion-between-itachiuchiha-and-emrage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hotfix**, try adding the following code inside `start()`

```
primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(windowEvent -> {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
});
```